# Permissions error in VirtualBox trying to install Drupal 7

Tags: virtualbox, installation, ubuntu-12.04, vagrant, drupal

I am trying to install Drupal 7 in a VirtualBox running Ubuntu, used Vagrant to set up the VirtualBox.

On the third step of the installation I got an error

> File system    The directory sites/default/files is not writable. An
>   automated attempt to create this directory failed, possibly due to a
>   permissions problem. To proceed with the installation, either create
>   the directory and modify its permissions manually or ensure that the
>   installer has the permissions to create it automatically. For more
>   information, see INSTALL.txt or the online handbook.

I have read and followed the instructions [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-drupal-on-a-virtual-server-running-ubuntu-12-04)

I already executed the commands below

```
chmod a+w sites/default/settings.php
chmod a+w sites/default
```

So as a last resort I created the sites/default/files directory manually

```
mkdir files
chmod 777 files
```

But I still get the same error message after changing the permissions on the folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The execute bit is also needed on parent directories under which the directory in question is located. So depending on ownership, some combination of user/group/other permission masks must combine to grant the requesting user the execute bit for each parent directory. E.g. If sites/ and sites/default are group-owned by the user who executes PHP (call them www-data), then you must ensure both directories have the execute bit set for the group mask `chmod g+x sites/ sites/default/`. If www-data is neither an owner nor group owner of the parents, then the other mask must be set similarly: `chmod o+x sites/ sites/default/`.

Comment: So does this mean that I have to do chown on the directories?

Answer (score 0):

This is should work in a dev environment. Not safe in production. In ubuntu, the username for the web server is www-data.

Go to the root directory of your website (where index.php is), and and run
sudo chown -R yourusername:www-data ./
sudo chmod -R 770 ./
sudo chmod -R 775 sites/default/files